# Is this use of UndecidableInstances okay? Alternatives?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, type-families

I would like to do some magic in a library, allowing a product type to be destructured polymorphically. This is a more or less working mockup illustrating what I'd like to do:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-} 
newtype Wrapped a = Wrapped { unwrap :: a } 

-- our example structure
ex :: (Int, (Int, Int))
ex = (1,(2,3))

class WrapDecomp x y | y -> x where
    decomp :: x -> y

instance (WrapDecomp x x', WrapDecomp y y')=> WrapDecomp (x,y) (x',y') where
    decomp (x,y) = (decomp x, decomp y)

instance WrapDecomp x (Wrapped x) where
    decomp = Wrapped


example = let w = decomp ex
              (w0, w1) = decomp ex
              (w0', (w1', w2')) = decomp ex :: (Wrapped Int, (Wrapped Int, Wrapped Int))
           in print $ ( unwrap w, unwrap w0, unwrap $ snd w1, unwrap $ fst w1 )
         -- Also works:
         -- in print $ ( unwrap w, unwrap w0, unwrap w1 )
```

My actual application is a library, and will have two properties that make the warts *I noticed* in the above acceptable:

1. the `Wrapped` type constructor is not exported
2. the user will always be calling `unwrap` on all `Wrapped` data in a binding (because of boring details of my application), so there shouldn't be ambiguity in practice

The consensus seems to be that `UndecidableInstances` isn't really bad, but I'd like to be sure the above is kosher before I proceed.

---

### Update w/ solution

I puzzled with this for a bit, but I was able to solve my problem with `TypeFamilies` as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
class Out a where
    type In a :: *
    decomp :: In a -> a

instance Out (Wrapped a) where
    type In (Wrapped a) = a
    decomp = Wrapped

instance (Out a, Out b)=> Out (a,b) where
    type In (a,b) = (In a,In b)
    decomp (x,y) = (decomp x, decomp y)
```

Comment: I couldn't tell if you had noticed the similarity to the type class "Newtype" in the [`newtype` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/newtype/0.2/doc/html/Control-Newtype.html) Your instance for pairs of wrapped things is different from anything that library seems to be anticipating, though.

Comment: hadn't heard of that package before, thanks! I'm not sure it helps me here though.

Comment: @jberryman I was wrong. You can write expressions with those instances that make the type checker loop. However, that much remains true: the context-stack prevents the type checker from actually looping, and code that compiles (i.e. without loop-causing expressions) is safe.

Comment: @DanielFischer IYI I figured out a solution using `TypeFamilies` and edited above. Thanks for helping me understand `UndecidableInstances`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The use of `UndecidableInstances` alone is kosher in general, what `UndecidableInstances` does is allow the type checker to try to resolve instances when it can't prove in advance that it will finish. If it does, the code is no less safe than if termination could have been proved in advance.

However, with your instances, you can create a situation where the type checker would loop with an expression that causes a constraint `WrapDecomp x (x,y)`, for example

```
foo x = [fst $ decomp x, x]
```

The use of `fst` requires `decomp x` to have type `(a,b)` for some types `a` and `b`, thus an `instance WrapDecomp t (a,b)` where `t` is the type of `x`. Being in the same list requires that `x` have tape `a` too, so an

```
instance WrapDecomp a (a,b)
```

The only instance with a pair for the second parameter is

```
instance (Wrapdecomp x x', WrapDecomp y y') => WrapDecomp (x,y) (x',y')
```

hence `a = (x,y)` for some types `x` and `y` and the constraint of `foo` becomes

```
WrapDecomp (x,y) ((x,y),b)
```

The pairs instance says there is such an instance if there are instances

```
WrapDecomp y b
```

and

```
WrapDecomp x (x,y)
```

which is the exact form of instance we started with.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! that clarifies things. It seems you're the unofficial UndecidableInstances hand-holder ;)

Comment: Isn't `UndecidableInstances`, in this case, only required to lift the coverage condition?